# Acceleration formula for a differential steering robot

Tags: ros, wheeled-robot, differential-drive

I have the formulas to derive the RPM's of each wheel from the robot's linear velocity.
Now, I am trying to do the same thing for the acceleration (mainly angular acceleration).
For linear acceleration I am always assuming that the linear velocity of the wheels is the same as the robots when the robot is moving on a straight line...according to physics. Am I right?

But angular acceleration seems more complicated, specially when the robot is following a curved path (not necessarily turning in place).

Any readings or ROS packages that deal with this acceleration issue?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate position of differential drive robot](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/1653/calculate-position-of-differential-drive-robot)

Comment: What about the acceleration?

Comment: Acceleration is just $\frac{{\Delta} v}{{\Delta}t} $, so if you can solve for the position then you have enough data to solve for the velocity and acceleration just by measuring the changes over time.